# Ignore parent directory in Git version control

Tags: git, gitignore

How to ignore parent directory in `.gitignore`?
I tried this patterns, but seems they are don't work:

```
/../*
../
../*
```

Comment: I'm a bit curious why don't you create another `.gitignore` in the parent folder instead of specifying it in it's child's `.gitignore` file

Comment: Afaik it is not possible (see @nXqd s answer). Also I think it is _highly_ confusing, if you (and of course git itself) must search not only the parent folders, but also _every_ subfolder and sub-subfolder to find out, which folders are ignored and why.

Comment: I'm confused. Why do you want to ignore a parent directory in `.gitignore`? Is the parent directory in the same git repository?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't, if you want your `.gitignore` to be versioned.

And if it is versioned, that means elements of the parent folder is versioned as well (and cannot be ignored without removing from the index all of its content).
[Kingcrunch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421223/kingcrunch) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488902/ignore-parent-directory-in-git-version-control/19489007#comment28906263_19489007) you could still version the `.gitignore` with a `git add -f`, but as commented before, this would be quite confusing.

If it best to place the `.gitignore` in the parent folder of the folder you want to ignore.
And *there* declare the name of the folder you want to ignore:

```
folder_to_ignore/
```

(Note the final '`/`')

Comment: You can still add ignored files with `git add -f filename`. Thats a common use case when you want to track empty folders. "ignore" just means, that it is hidden `git status` and `git add` (without `-f`)

Comment: @KingCrunch true, I have added that in the answer.

Comment: You can have multiple `.gitignore` files in different directories. An easy fix is to create another `.gitignore` file in the parent directory, then add the file you wish to ignore to it.

Comment: @IsaacLyman yes: you can see all the .gitignore files with: `git check-ignore -v -- afile`

Comment: So if I have a git repo with many sub-projects or sub-folders, and I only want to ignore files in one sub-project, I cannot?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Sure you can: see the second part of my other answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/50886524/6309.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to ignore a folder but don't want to modify an existing .gitignore, drop a .gitignore in the folder containing only an asterisk.

```
*
```

Here is a quick BASH example to accomplish this task for the .idea folder:

```
$ echo '*' > .idea/.gitignore
```