# Ignoring everything in .gitignore and adding subfolder does not work

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the following .gitignore:

```
# Ignore everything
/*
!/.gitignore

# Readd folders:
#!/mainfolder/ # this works!
!/mainfolder/subfolder/
!/mainfolder/subfolder/*
```

I want to ignore everything, but `subfolder/`. Adding the line `!/mainfolder/` works, so that /mainfolder is not ignored anymore. But I want to add only the things below `subfolder/` and the second and third lines for `subfolder/` do not work.

I have found several links online suggesting this is the correct way (e.g. [this one](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Using-gitignore-to-hide-all-but-specific-directory/qaq-p/177245)). So what am I doing wrong?!

EDIT: I am using Git 2.17.1 from SourceTree on Windows 10. I have tested these results from the integrated MINGW64 bash.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.gitignore exclude folder but include specific subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5533050/gitignore-exclude-folder-but-include-specific-subfolder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to whitelist folders first, then files:

```
*
!.gitignore
!/mainfolder/
/mainfolder/*
!/mainfolder/subfolder/
!/mainfolder/subfolder/**
```

For any file still ignored, check why with:

```
git check-ignore -v -- path/to/ignored/file
```

---

> would it be possible to extend the answer on how you would do this for a deeper subfolder? E.g. how would I ignore everything except ´deepsubfolder´(?): !/mainfolder/subfolder/deepsubfolde

That is similar to "[Git - Unignore any folder located anywhere inside repository that recursively allows everything](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50398712/6309)":

```
*
!.gitignore
!*/
!**/deepsubfolder/**
```

Comment: This works. I know it was not part of the original question, but would it be possible to extend the answer on how you would do this for a deeper subfolder? E.g. how would I ignore everything except ´deepsubfolder´(?):
!/mainfolder/subfolder/deepsubfolder

Comment: Place ** before deep: sub/**/deep/**

Comment: So this:

!/mainfolder/subfolder/**/deepsubfolder/
!/mainfolder/subfolder/**/deepsubfolder/**

instead of this(?):

!/mainfolder/subfolder/
!/mainfolder/subfolder/**

Because that did not work.

Comment: You missed the trailing /: when the last element is a folder, always add the /

Comment: Sorry. I accidentally sent the comment prematurely and edited it while you answered. Could you briefly look over it again. The trailing / does not appear to help. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: I am on my phone, I will look at it when I go back

Comment: In the meantime, have a look at my old answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50357571/git-unignore-any-folder-located-anywhere-inside-repository-that-recursively-al/50398712#50398712