# Gitignore file not ignoring files from above directory

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm trying to configure my `.gitignore` file so that I don't track any of my log files. However, it's not working properly and I'm not sure what's wrong.

Right now, the directory structure looks like this:

```
project_name
    - logs
        - logfile1
        - logfile2
    - src
        - file1.py
        - file2.py
        - .git
        - .gitignore
        - __pycache__/
```

The contents of my `.gitignore` file are:

```
__pycache__/
../logs/
logs/
../logs/log*
```

It's ignoring `__pycache__` just fine, but Git is telling me that logs needs to be tracked.

Comment: Maybe you could create another .gitignore in the above directory?

Comment: That actually did the trick, thanks. Is it impossible to handle files in other directories with one .gitignore?

Comment: Why should that ignore be able to control files in other directories that is not a descendant?

Comment: If you want to handle files with one .gitignore, I think you need to put the .gitignore file in the top directory of your git repo.

Comment: @JeffMercado I'm not saying it should, I was just curious as to whether it's possible or not.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488902/ignore-parent-directory-in-git-version-control, I think it's not possible. Maybe the source code of the git would explain why.

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out why you would expect it to. Your directory is like a box and the ignore file describes what is not in the box. You shouldn't expect it to describe what's not in other boxes.

Comment: @JeffMercado Ah that makes sense. I only thought that it may be possible to handle other directories as well, I wasn't aware that the hierarchy should be taken into account.

Comment: @Seankala It's not possible what you are asking, see documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Documentation](http://%20git-scm.com/docs/gitignore) is specific about that (emphasis mine):

> Patterns read from a .gitignore file **in the same directory as the path, or in any parent directory**, with patterns in the higher level files (up to the toplevel of the work tree) being overridden by those in lower level files down to the directory containing the file.

Your `.gitignore` file is not in any of the parent directories of `logs` directory, so it has no effect.